# How many different crews have a robot as leader? exactly one robot on the crew? at least one robot on the crew?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I can solve for how many ways there is to choose five team members from $16$ workers $= 16C5$.  But, I'm having a hard time figuring how to approach the other question can anyone guide me in the right direction?

There are a total of $16$ workers made up $9$ humans and $7$ robots. There are five roles: leader, navigator, doctor, operator, and technician. Each role has to filled by a different worker. How many different crews have

1) a robot as leader?

2) exactly one robot on the crew?

3) at least one robot on the crew?

Answer (score 1):

1) There are 7 ways to pick the leader and then 15x14x13x12 ways to complete the team. You must then multiply these numbers.

2) There are 7 ways to pick the robot and so the 5 roles for the robot gives 35 possibilities, There are then 9x8x7x6 ways of completing the team.

3) Find the number of teams without any robots and subtract this from the total number of teams. Over to you but ask if you are unsure of your answer.

Comment: Ok so a crew with no robots is 9C5 so we use 16C5 and subtract 9C5 from it ?

Comment: Although you are right in thinking that 16C5 is the number of ways of picking the 5 members,  the number of teams is much bigger because they have to be assigned roles.

Comment: I know this sounds dumb but I don't really understand what your saying. It feels like i'm wasting your time sorry.

Comment: It does depend on what is meant by different crew! I think it means that a crew with the roles filled by entities A,B,C,D,E is different from one with the roles filled by, say, B,A,C,E,D in that order

Comment: Otherwise there would have been little point in the question having the different roles

Comment: ok so i just need to rearrange all the possible ways to find the total number of teams right ? assuming that its like what you thought?

Comment: That's it - well done.

Comment: Man thank you so much for taking the time to help me I hope I didn't waste too much of your time.

Comment: You're welcome!